# Mongoose trigger on insert data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Im useing nest js framework with mongoose, I need to implement trigger on one of my tables and send notification to users when a record insert ro table please tell me what is the best practice to do this in nest js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NestJS mongoose module supports hooks. Check out the docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#hooks-middleware).

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: Cat.name,
        useFactory: () => {
          const schema = CatsSchema;
          schema.pre('save', function() { console.log('Hello from pre save') });
          return schema;
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another avenue you may be interested in is something called Change Streams, which are native in MongoDB. Essentially, you "watch" for changes on a collection/document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/changeStream/